# Git push unresponsive

Tags: git, bitbucket

Facing an issue with git where it does not complete the process of "git push" and just stands still like it would happen in an infinite loop. 
I read a little bit about this online, Would this be space problem may be ?

I also tried "git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000". That did not help either.

Pasting my steps below:

```
$ git status -s
M cli/filename1.php
M cli/filename2.php
M cli/filename3.php
M cli/testDelete.php

$ git add -A

$ git commit -m " my msg "
[branch_name 45ec72e]  my msg
4 files changed, 93 insertions(+), 15 deletions(-)

$ git push origin branch_name
Password for 'https://username@bitbucket.org':
<cursor keeps blinking here, it has been such since more than 20 mins now.>
```

I do not get any error . 
Also another interesting thing to note is (1) I do get a fatal: authentication failed when I feed in the incorrect password, it goes into an unresponsive state when I feed in the correct password and (2) when I interrupt by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and run git status -s again - it shows no files. But when I check it in my repo online, the files do no exist there.

Comment: Well, you do need to input the password.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you weren't the first guy to pick "username" so I'm guessing you'll need to update that to your username if you haven't

Comment: Well, I did enter my password. It gets unresponsive after that.
My username is not actually "username". I edited it before I posted it . 
But now I am kinda stuck. I am thinking about may be re installing git? I am not sure though. I would appreciate any kind of help.
Thanks you guys for taking a look at it. :)

Comment: Is this a new issue, or have you never been able to push to bitbucket? Have you tried setting up an SSH key and using git over SSH?

Comment: Hey Noah, this is a new issue. I was able to successfully execute "git push" before. It is something that just recently stopped working for me. I have not tried setting up an SSH key. I honestly don't know how to do that. If you can guide me maybe? that would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Noah ,  I have not tried setting up an SSH, but I doubt that would be the issue ? What do you think ?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still having this issue, try configuring your username and email just as it is set in bitbucket.

```
git config --global user.name "JohnDoe"
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```